# Getting error "You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded" when I try start server

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have started getting the following error when I try to run 'rails s' on my local machine:

```
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded (i.e. the Spring constant is defined).

This is probably because you generated binstubs with Spring 1.0, and you now have a Spring version > 1.0 on your system. To solve this, upgrade your bundle to the latest Spring version and then run `bundle exec spring binstub --all` to regenerate your binstubs. This is a one-time step necessary to upgrade from 1.0 to 1.1.

Here's the backtrace:

/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `load'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `block in load'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:319:in `load'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/spring-2.1.0/lib/spring/binstub.rb:11:in `<main>'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:92:in `require'
/Users/emmetgibney/Dropbox/Programming/tableread/tableread/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

I have Spring version 2.1.0 installed on my machine. I have run the command the error message asks, `bundle exec spring binstub --all` and the error persists. I read on another SO answer to try running `bundle exec spring binstub --remove --all` which did remove then binstubs, I then ran the first command again to regenerate them. Still getting the same error.

The problem persists even on other rails apps. For example, when I switch to another app on my machine and run `rails s` I get the same error, even though I might not have worked on that app for weeks.

The problem started after installing Docsplit and its required dependencies, along with google-cloud-text_to_speech. Probably worth noting that my system won't allow me to uninstall the google-cloud-text_to_speech gem as well.

I'm using MacOS 10.13.6

Comment: I have now also tried completely removing rbenv and all of my gems, then reinstalling rbenv. I was hoping that by cleaning everything up I'd resolve the issue. Unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: I managed to solve the problem. When I removed spring and tried to start my rails server I got the following message:

/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': dlopen(/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)

I thought perhaps it was a problem with postgres. I uninstalled and reinstalled postgres using brew, and that seems to have resolved it

Answer (score 2):

Maybe regenerate your gemspecs
try running ...

```
gem pristine --all
bundle install
bundle exec spring binstub --all
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem. When I removed the spring gem and tried to start my rails server I got the following message:

```
/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.6/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require': dlopen(/Users/emmetgibney/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/pg-1.2.3/lib/pg_ext.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
```

This made me think it could be a problem with postgres, so I uninstalled and reinstalled postgres using brew, and that seems to have resolved it. I can now start my rails server for this app, and all my other apps as well.

I hadn't done involving postgres since installing it WAY back when, so I have no idea how postgres got messed up in the first place, but it works now nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you, in my case the error was not related with spring either and removing spring showed me the actual error (which was related with another gem)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was due to postgres gem in my Gemfile. I was using sqlite3 on my development server and postgres on production (Heroku). So pg gem was without a group wrapper.

I solved it by wrapping postgres with a production group wrapper like so:

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My problem was I had Postgres installed with homebrew, and then I had Postgres.app installed as well. The Postgres.app version was the one I was running, and the one that would start when I typed `psql` into terminal, but rbenv could not access it.

I was able to follow the steps [here](https://postgresapp.com/documentation/configuration-ruby.html).

First make sure you have your `$PATH` variable set up correctly. If you don't, run

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
```

and then restart your terminal.

After you have confirmed that or run the command to update it, run

```
sudo ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install pg
```

and you should be good to go. Just make sure your `config/database.yaml` is setup properly, something like;

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: [YOUR_DATABASE_NAME]
  host: localhost
```

And to finally run `rails db:migrate` and `rails db:setup` to set up the database and `rails server` to start the server, hopefully without issue.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after creating a new rails app with Postgres, running a local server (which worked), upgrading from `Ruby 2.7.0 > 2.7.2`, bundling, and trying to run the server again.

I was getting this error over and over (even after running the `binstub` command):

```
You've tried to invoke Spring when it's already loaded ...
```

This soloved my issue

1. Delete the `.bundle` folder
2. clean `bundle install`

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this exact situation 30 minutes ago. I'm using ArchLinux. I do have the latest Ruby from the ArchLinux community. But the project I'm working on uses Ruby 2.7, and I'm using RVM for that.

Today suddenly I saw `rails s` isn't working. I quickly ran `bundle exec spring binstub --all`, but I got:

```
* bin/rake: Spring already present
* bin/rails: Spring already present
```

So I read the package update log (`/var/log/pacman.log`), and I got this:

```
[2021-10-20T12:33:44+0530] [ALPM] upgraded libffi (3.3-4 -> 3.4.2-4)
[2021-10-20T12:33:44+0530] [ALPM] upgraded glib2 (2.70.0-1 -> 2.70.0-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:44+0530] [ALPM] upgraded gobject-introspection-runtime (1.70.0-1 -> 1.70.0-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:44+0530] [ALPM] upgraded gjs (2:1.68.3-1 -> 2:1.68.3-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded python (3.9.7-1 -> 3.9.7-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded gobject-introspection (1.70.0-1 -> 1.70.0-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded guile (2.2.7-1 -> 2.2.7-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded libp11-kit (0.24.0-1 -> 0.24.0-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded p11-kit (0.24.0-1 -> 0.24.0-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded libfilezilla (0.34.0-1 -> 0.34.1-1)
[2021-10-20T12:33:45+0530] [ALPM] upgraded llvm-libs (12.0.1-4 -> 12.0.1-5)
[2021-10-20T12:33:46+0530] [ALPM] upgraded llvm (12.0.1-4 -> 12.0.1-5)
[2021-10-20T12:33:46+0530] [ALPM] upgraded ocaml-ctypes (0.17.1-6 -> 0.17.1-8)
[2021-10-20T12:33:46+0530] [ALPM] upgraded llvm-ocaml (12.0.1-4 -> 12.0.1-5)
[2021-10-20T12:33:46+0530] [ALPM] upgraded mpg123 (1.29.0-1 -> 1.29.1-1)
[2021-10-20T12:33:46+0530] [ALPM] upgraded python-cffi (1.14.6-1 -> 1.14.6-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:46+0530] [ALPM] upgraded python-gobject (3.40.1-1 -> 3.40.1-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:47+0530] [ALPM] upgraded python2 (2.7.18-4 -> 2.7.18-5)
[2021-10-20T12:33:47+0530] [ALPM] upgraded wayland (1.19.0-1 -> 1.19.0-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:47+0530] [ALPM] upgraded qt5-base (5.15.2+kde+r243-1 -> 5.15.2+kde+r247-1)
[2021-10-20T12:33:48+0530] [ALPM] upgraded qscintilla-qt5 (2.13.0-1 -> 2.13.1-1)
[2021-10-20T12:33:48+0530] [ALPM] upgraded ruby (3.0.2-1 -> 3.0.2-2)
[2021-10-20T12:33:49+0530] [ALPM] upgraded ruby-docs (3.0.2-1 -> 3.0.2-2)
```

As you can see there's a `libffi` update and the Archlinux community built Ruby, Python, LLVM and even Glibc on the new libffi. So, for RVM ruby's `ffi` gem, it was a soname bump.

So **I downgraded `libffi`** and it's working. But this might **break the system** when you reboot it because glibc is built against the new `libffi`. So I have to keep **latest libffi and rebuild the ffi gem** that the bundler specifies. So this will solve the issue:

```
$ gem uninstall ffi -aI

# If you have Gemfile
$ bundle install

# If you don't have Gemfile
$ gem install ffi
```

So `libffi` bump was a different reason for the problem. And rebuilding FFI native extension will fix this.

Comment: Many root causes for this symptom. I just had the same issue as you, thank you for the instructions! 

Comment: a simple `bundle update ffi` worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem after upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. The solution in [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/t/rails-cant-run-rails-server-with-spring-gem/253633) DID NOT WORK for me with Ruby 2.7.0 and Rails 6.0.3.2

However this [How to get FFI working on Ruby 2.7.2 image](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/how-to-get-ffi-working-on-ruby-2-7-2-image/37787/2) worked for me.

Basically, this works if it was an upgraded

```sh
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.7 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libffi.so.6
```

Answer (score 0):

i removed 'spring' gem, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps:

1. Remove Spring gem from gemfile.
2. `bundle install`
3. Delete `Vendor` file from project.
4. `bundle install`.
5. then `rails s`.

Answer (score 0):

`bundle pristine` or `gem pristine --all` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same after updating my app to rails 6.1.4.1.

1. Delete `Gemfile.lock`
2. `bundle install`